# Using a list as parameters for a function

Tags: python

I'm have a list like this `['a1,b1,c1', 'a2,b2,c2', 'a3,b3,d3']` 
and I'm trying to either write a **function** or a **for loop** that will take each set up these numbers as inputs
so for example the first time it runs `a=a1, b=b1, c=c1`, the second time it'll run `a=a2, b=b2 c=c2` as inputs

I've seen a few threads using functions with asterisks like this `some_func(*params)`
but I don't see how to make it a loop that kind of takes a combination of inputs like how I wanted it to

or would using a **dict** be able to address and do this?

an example would be like (sorry not making it superr specific and concrete)

```
def apply(a, b, c):

x = something
y = something_else

(hello, there) = somefunction(x, y, size=a) 

sky = anotherfunction(beta[1], put=b, call=c)
```

any help is appreciated, or if there has been a similar question before, happy for it to be linked

Comment: a1 is not a number

Comment: You have a string with commas as input - you would need to parse it first.

Comment: thanks, yeah I'm using a1 here to represent else putting all the numbers here makes it more confusing?

Comment: as in, turn them into separate lists?

Comment: There is not inbuild method developed to achieve something like this, you need to have two methods, an outer and an inner method, outer calls the inner method by looping over the ith indices of each array

Comment: So the list is something like `["1,2,3", "4,5,6"]`?

Comment: yep, with possible repetitive numbers like `["1,2,3", "1,5,6"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a list `strings` and function `func`

```
strings = ['a1,b1,c1', 'a2,b2,c2', 'a3,b3,d3']

def func(a, b, c):
    # your function
    pass
```

Structure will be

```
for string in string:
    func(*map(int, string.split(",")))
```

the `map(int, string.split(","))` will split string and make a list like `[1, 2, 3]` for `'1,2,3'`.

Then the `*` symbol will spread the numbers one for each parameter, for list `[1, 2, 3]` will call the function like `func(a=1, b=2, c=3)`.

Comment: hello, just an add-on question, if say some value in `a, b, c` is a float, would they be able to be float and intergers as they are, or I must decide whether to keep them as float or intergers at the `func(*map(int, string.split(",")))`?

Comment: @jaxan I think it depends on you and what you need to do

Comment: @jaxan if you want to do that, you can write `[(int(x) if x.isnumeric() else float(x)) for x in string.split(',')]` in one line instead of the map, you can also do a multiline on your own.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, use variadic arguments as follows:

```
def fun(*args):
    """Toy function"""
    return sum(args) + 10


arguments = ["1,2,3", "1,5,6"]

for argument in arguments:
    res = fun(*map(int, argument.split(",")))
    print(res)
```

**Output**

```
16
22
```

The expression:

```
map(int, argument.split(","))
```

creates an iterable of integers from the `argument` string. The `*` unpacks these arguments.

Comment: thanks! but what if in the case where the a, b and c is spreaded out in the function? like say `test = 1 + 2 + a `------------ `test2 = b` ----------- `hello = (x = 1, y =2, z =c)`, would this also be able to work?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand those examples

Comment: say like instead of being able to use `sum(args)`, `a, b, c` is used differently (called different times, and maybe even multiple times inside the function)

Comment: sorry for making it confusing

Comment: Perhaps if you add a few more *concrete* examples, it would help me and others understand your question better

Comment: I kind of edited the question abit including an example, but it's still not entirely specific, would this kind of make more sense? thanks!!

Comment: thanks dani for trying to help as well!! again sorry I'm dumb and creating all those unnecessary confusion